# What did Priya warn Protagonist about?

Tags: tenet

Priya and Protagonist are talking about universe where Kat won't get hurt and Sator
won't get the algorithm:

> Priya: If that universe can exist...we don't live in it.
>
> Protagonist: Well, let's try. You're going to **warn me**.

What did Priya warn Protagonist about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that she actually doesn't warn the protagonist at all - although he is trying to instruct her to do so.

From Priya's point of view, the Oslo meeting with the Protagonist happens two days before their encounter in Mumbai.

> Priya
> What have I done?
>
> Protagonist
> It’s something you do. In two days, you’ll get me to use plutonium as an arms dealer bait. I want to know why.

Priya then reveals during the Oslo meeting that it was not plutonium, but rather the final piece of the algorithm.

The Protagonist wants Priya to warn him in Mumbai about what will (from her point of view) take place in Tallinn. However, she proceeds to lay out the plan - whoever is planning this actually wanted Sator to get the final piece so he will bring them all together which will allow Tenet to retrieve all nine pieces algorithm in one swoop.

So, she doesn't warn him of anything and the Mumbai conversation takes place exactly as the Protagonist has already experienced it.